# Why am I getting a Syntax error for this IF statement?

Tags: python

```
> > `x=18.0  If x < 18.5:
> >     print("Less than 18.5")`
```

I'm expecting it to print but instead I get this error
`If x < 18.5: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I'm using Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook.

`a = 33 b = 200 if b > a: print("b is greater than a")` This code works but not the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are capitalizing if, also your indentation is wrong, it should look something like

```
x = 18.0
if x < 18.5:
    print("Less than 18.5")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` shouldn't be capitalized in your code.